# tailLines and SinceTime in logging api,both not worked simultaneously

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am using container engine, and my pods are hosted there.

I am trying to fetch logs, using log api :

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/app-test/pods/designer-0/log?**tailLines**=100&**sinceTime**=2017-09-17T10:47:58Z

if i used both the query params separately, it works and show the proper result, but if i am using it simultaneously only the top 100 logs are returning, the **sinceTime** param is get ignored.

my scenario is, i need a log from a specific time, in a chunk like, 100 lines, 100 lines.. like this.

I am not sure, whether it is a bug, or it is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from the api reference manual

https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/

```
tailLines -     If set, the number of lines from the end of the logs to 
show. If not specified, logs are shown from the creation of the 
container or sinceSeconds or sinceTime
```

So, that means if you specify tailLines, it start from the end. I dont see any option explicitly mentioned other than `limitBytes`. But you will have to play around with it as it does not guarantee number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

tailLines=X tells the server to start that many lines from the end

sinceTime tells the server to start from the specified time

the options are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I have later on recognized that, it is not ignoring the sinceTime, as the TailLines intended functionality is return the lines from the last.

So, if i mentioned the sinceTime= 10 PM yesterday, it will return the records from that time..And if also tailLines, is mentioned, so it will return the recent logs from that chunk.

So, it was working as expected. I need to play with **LimitBytes** for getting the logs in chunk, from that time, Instead of full logs.